# how to hide number pad in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

i have two text-Fields one is for Username and second is  for mobile-number

username:
 it is possible for me to  hide keyboard  for username Text-Fields  by using this method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

My problem is 
mobile-number :

How to hide mobile-number Text-Field?

Comment: You should adopt this [implementation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991085/how-to-dismiss-number-pad-keyboard-by-tapping-anywhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone

Comment: can you explain some more info of what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use following [library](https://github.com/broderboy/iphone-DoneCancelNumberPadToolbar) to add done and cancel button on the number pad.

Also You can use tap gesture to hide the number pad.Use following code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
 {
 [textField resignFirstResponder];//Assuming that UITextField Object is textField
 }
```

This will work for you..Happy Coding!! Cheers..!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self addTapGesture];
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark Gesture  methods

- (void) addTapGesture {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = FALSE;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

Comment: Judging from the given code it's obvious that he wants to hide the keyboard with the return key, but the number pad doesn't have a return key, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options open to you, you need to decide when you want to dismiss your textfields numeric keyboard. For example, if you have a set number of digits you need before you dismiss you could subscribe to

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidChange:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Then in implement something along the lines of

```
-(void)textFieldTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UITextField *textfield = notification.object;

    if(textfield.text.length == NUMBER_OF_DIGITS_NEEDED)
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

If your user also needs to be able to dismiss the keyboard at their discretion, you should put a tap gesture recognizer on the remaining visible view.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGestureRecogniser.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecogniser];

-(void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecogniser
{
    if ([self.myTextField isFirstResponder])
        [self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```