# How to detect a tap outside a UITextField (to dismiss key board)

Tags: ios, uitextfield

My iPhone App has a numerical text-field (and some other controls). A num pad is shown when the user taps the text field.  I like to dismiss this num pad (by `[self.textField resignFirstResponder]`) as soon as the 
user taps on the view's background (easy to detect) ***but also*** when the user taps on any **other** control!

How can I detect that the user taps outside the text field (but not necessarily on the background)?

Comment: You have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991085/how-to-dismiss-number-pad-keyboard-by-tapping-anywhere?rq=1).

Comment: It does not work so well if the user taps another control (and not the background)

Comment: You could resign the first responder on the actions of the other controls.

Comment: Yes, but I hope there is some other way...

Answer (score 3):

I always do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

and then implement:

```
- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks, it works semi-good. It works when the user touches a slider, but not when he/she touches a segmented-control.

Comment: add `[self dismissKeyboard]` in the first line of your action method for your segmented control and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @reecon's answer about `touchesBegan`. I wouldn't recommend to use it as you'd end up with a jumping keyboard up and down when the user taps repeatedly and believe me, it looks totally weird (at least it was on iOS 7.1.1 in one of my projects).

I'd go for the good old full screen `UITapGestureRecognizer`. You could also use a full screen `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with a `down` direction - it would look and feel even cooler, as if the user is sliding down a keyboard.

Both gestures are added through the IB and require no code to set up.

Tapping on "other controls" is a totally different story though and you'd have to do it all by hand - no gestures can help you.