# How to add touchesBegan action programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add a code where if the user tap anywhere outside the Text Field, the keyboard will close. So I met this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991085/how-to-dismiss-number-pad-keyboard-by-tapping-anywhere). But I don't know how to implement the binding to the function touchesBegan because I alloc all the view component programmatically, including the subview container and textfield within that subview container. How to do that? I think this is just a line of code, but I don't know what code to expect and what words I have to use to search on google (I've tried to search for it but can't quite find what I'm looking for), so I'm lost. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subclasses of `UIView`s can implement touchesBegan. You should put the touchesBegan on the UITextField superview.

Comment: Oh, but I have viewContainer as UITextField superview. and the viewContainer has self.view as superview. How can I implement the touchesBegan on the viewContainer?

Comment: Nevermind, it works when I put it at self.view anyway. Thanks!

Comment: As I've read the touchesBegan method is available on UIResponder subclasses.